# Vuejs with Laravel production: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, production-environment, webpack-production

this question might asked before but the sulotions sugested did not solve my problem.

I'm using Vue2 inside Laravel 7, in Live vps server when I run `npm run prod` I get below error.

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

and this here is the full error

```
> @ prod /var/www/html/exptradies
> npm run production


> @ production /var/www/html/exptradies
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js


<--- Last few GCs --->

[3521:0x302b050]   110565 ms: Mark-sweep 489.2 (517.6) -> 485.0 (517.6) MB, 1150.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.155, current mu = 0.100) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[3521:0x302b050]   111997 ms: Mark-sweep 489.2 (517.6) -> 485.0 (517.6) MB, 1222.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.150, current mu = 0.146) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x384b92cc08d1 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: concat(this=0x0871a8909981 <JSArray[0]>,0x0871a8909961 <JSArray[0]>,0x0871a8909981 <JSArray[0]>)

    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x20144909fd61] [/var/www/html/exptradies/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=0x21c8562eee7d](this=0x349882d804b1 <undefined>,0x3c3d355838b9 <AST_Call map = 0x1ea8d45e1279>,0x0871a89...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa1ae50 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa1b25c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb9b20e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb9b589 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd58815  [node]
 6: 0xd58ea6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xd65765 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xd66615 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xd690cc v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xd2f752 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawWithAllocationSite(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::AllocationSite>) [node]
11: 0xd3b104 v8::internal::Factory::NewJSArrayWithUnverifiedElements(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>, v8::internal::ElementsKind, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
12: 0xd3b549 v8::internal::Factory::NewJSArray(v8::internal::ElementsKind, int, int, v8::internal::ArrayStorageAllocationMode, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
13: 0xec65c3 v8::internal::ElementsAccessor::Concat(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Arguments*, unsigned int, unsigned int) [node]
14: 0xc0a565  [node]
15: 0xc12dfd v8::internal::Builtin_ArrayConcat(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
16: 0x140e919  [node]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-02T16_32_12_621Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ prod: `npm run production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-02T16_32_12_662Z-debug.log
```

there are `npm` and `node` version

```
jawadi@groovy-voyage:/$ npm --version
6.14.16
jawadi@groovy-voyage:/$ node --version
v12.22.12
```

this is `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js").sass(
    "resources/sass/app.scss",
    "public/css"
);

mix.browserSync(process.env.APP_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this command:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
npm run prod
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).